# Users_not_found in HTTParty request to SlackAPI when curl works

Tags: ruby, slack-api, httparty

I'm trying to use GET request using httparty gem to have info about specific user from SlackAPI. From curl it works well

`curl --data "token=SLACK_TOKEN&email=user@example.com" https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail`

But my code below seems to be broken because I received an error `{"ok":false,"error":"users_not_found"}`

```
module Slack
  class GetUserId
    def call
      response = HTTParty.get("https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail", payload: payload, headers: headers)
    end

    def headers
      {
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer SLACK_TOKEN'
      }
    end

    def payload
      {
         email: "user@example.com"
      }.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check their documentation, it seems that API do not accept JSON-form but rather  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
 
So something like:

```
headers: {
  'Authorization' => 'Bearer SLACK_TOKEN,
   "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     },
body: {
     "token=SLACK_TOKEN”,
     ”email=user@example.com" 
    ...
```

Reference: https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I think I defined POST method for httparty instead of GET where params are in url but I don't know how to pass it - https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/aaws.rb#L23

Comment: @Fernand is correct. That method does not support JSON encoding, only form encoding. But in addition that also means that you have to put the token in the body, not in the auth header.